# If I want to modify some functions in AOSP, what is the best way to find out the source code?

Tags: android-source

For example, I want to change the UI of the authorization when new app is installed, but I have no idea where to find the source code in AOSP.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I am trying to answer my own question. For now, the way I use to locate some function code is 1. open the app. 2. use `adb shell dumpsys activity` to check out which activity of which package is on focused. 3. Find the activity in AOSP and chase the code.